# Finding the location of one string within another string in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I couldn't find a function in BigQuery query reference which looks for one string within a second one and returns the index of the location. Something like instr() in other SQL dialects. Is there any substitute or any technique to achieve this?

For example: Looking into "de" in "abcdef" will return 4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way you can do this is with a Regular Expression extract ([see reference here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference#regularexpressionfunctions)):

```
SELECT
  title, LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT(title, r'^(.*)def.*')) + 1 AS location_of_fragment
FROM
  [publicdata:samples.wikipedia]
WHERE
  REGEXP_MATCH(title, r'^(.*)def.*')
LIMIT 10;
```

Returns:

```
Row title   location_of_fragment     
1   Austrian air defense    14   
2   Talk:Interface defeat   16   
3   High-definition television  6    
4   Talk:IAU definition of planet   10   
5   Wikipedia:Articles for deletion/Culture defines politics    41   
6   Wikipedia:WikiProject Spam/LinkReports/defenders.org    40   
7   Adenine phosphoribosyltransferase deficiency    35   
8   Stay-at-home defenceman 14   
9   Manganese deficiency (plant)    11   
10  High-definition television  6
```

Answer (score 8):

The old answer is now deprecated and @carlos answer works:

```
STRPOS(string, substring)
```

Answer (score 2):

The legacy SQL INSTR(str1,str2) function "Returns the one-based index of the first occurrence of a string." So that should work for you.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql

Comment: If you are looking for Standar SQL, then STRPOS(string, substring) "Returns the 1-based index of the first occurrence of substring inside string. Returns 0 if substring is not found".


https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#strpos

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but the BigQuery API changed, now the Regex syntax is as follow:

```
SELECT mydomains FROM `myproject.mydataset.mytable`
       where regexp_contains(mydomains, r'^(.*)example.*');
```

To answer the question with *For example: Looking into "de" in "abcdef" will return 4.*, it would look like:

```
SELECT de FROM `myproject.mydataset.mytable`
       where regexp_contains(de, r'^(.*)abcdef.*');
```

REGEXP_MATCH is now part of *Legacy SQL Functions and Operators* as per the reference link.

Hope it helps the one! :)